# Azure AD B2C reuses previous user's token after logout when user changes

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, federated-identity, msal.js

We have an application that uses MSAL.js to authenticate customers to their Azure Active Directories via Active Directory B2C. In the future we will introduce other IDPs in the mix and connect them to the B2C as well. B2C is configured via custom policies. SSO session scope is currently set to Tenant.
The issue is that when user logs out of the application (and we call MSAL.js logout) I can see their ID and Access tokens are gone from the browser Local Storage, but they are are still logged in to their Azure AD because of other apps using it. So next time they login to the app B2C will not prompt them for credentials and automatically sign them in as long as they have AAD session active. I understand this is by design for B2C to support SSO, and we want SSO. However is there a way for a new user with different credentials to login fresh after the previous user logs out in the same browser session?

Comment: Adding this parameter did not make a difference. I read somewhere that it doesn't work for external IDPs. And we are logging in to Azure AD as an external IDP via B2C .

Answer (score 1):

Set the prompt param to login. EG:

`GET https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? prompt=login`

Or using MSAL.js:

```js
var request = {
    prompt: 'login',
}

userAgentApplication.loginRedirect(request);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. The login prompt would come up every time though, hopefully it will be prefilled...

Comment: OK, that worked, but I also had to add <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="prompt" DefaultValue="{OIDC:prompt}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"/> to the AAD Claims Provider in B2C Custom Policies. Modifying MSAL.js request alone didn't make a difference.